# getting error while configuring wpa_spplicant in WPA3 SAE mode

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, wpa-supplicant

I configured as below in `wpa_supplicant2.conf`:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant 
ctrl_interface_group=0
sae_pwe=2
sae_groups=19 20 21 24 25
update_config=1
network={
    ssid=req_SSID
    proto=RSN
    key_mgmt=SAE 
    sae_pwe=2 
    pairwise=CCMP
    group=CCMP 
    ieee80211w=2 
    psk=PSD 
}
```

but while running this am getting following error

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Line 8: invalid key_mgmt 'SAE'
Line 8: no key_mgmt values configured.
Line 8: failed to parse key_mgmt 'SAE'.
Line 14: failed to parse network block.
Failed to read or parse configuration '/etc/wpa_supplicant_wpa2.conf'.
: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
```

Comment: What wpa_supplicant version are you using, and are you sure it was compiled with SAE support enabled?

Comment: wpa_supplicant v2.10